# Why did Commissioner Gordon dispose of his messages?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, zack-snyders-justice-league

Dr. Stone realizes that Mother Box was taken by Cyborg, then he was startled by a Parademon which landed behind him. The scene cuts to Gotham Police Department, where Commissioner Gordon receives a bundles of messages from a female officer, then walks side-by-side with Detective Crispus Allen:

> Commissioner Gordon: Don't have to see the sky to know it's a full moon.
>
> Crispus Allen: Half of Gotham's reality-challenged community showed up. Say they saw flying monsters by the harbor.

Then Commissioner Gordon disposes of his messages:

[image]

Why did Commissioner Gordon dispose of his messages?

Comment: Because he doesn't need to read them to know that it's bedlam out there.